# Java 7: Generic method to convert GET response to Generic Object

Tags: java, json, generics, optimization

I have a custom generic method which makes a `GET` request to a URL and converts the JSON response to the `responseType` object:

```
public static <T> Object getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException{
        Response getResponse = callWithHttpGet(url);
        String getResponseJson = getResponse.getBody();
        ObjectMapper getResponseJsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object obj = getResponseJsonMapper.readValue(getResponseJson, responseType);        
        return obj;
    }
```

The above code works fine if I call it as below:

```
Object person = getForEntity(PERSON_REST_URL,Person.class);
```

How do I make it work as below instead of returning an Object?

```
Person person = getForEntity(PERSON_REST_URL, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to pass a `Class<T>` parameter.

Note that you don't need a cast on the `readValue` method response because you already passed `clazz` as parameter so it returns a `clazz` element.

Your error was only that you assigned the result to an object of type Object. Than returned it. Remove the not necessary assignement and return directly from the result of the call to `readValue`.

```
public static <T> T getForEntity(String url, Class<T> clazz)  throws InterruptedException, 
                                                  ExecutionException, IOException {
    Response getResponse = callWithHttpGet(url);
    String getResponseJson = getResponse.getBody();
    ObjectMapper getResponseJsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return getResponseJsonMapper.readValue(getResponseJson, clazz);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, have the method return `T` instead of `Object`:

```
public static <T> T getForEntity(...)
```

then, implement it to return a T. `readValue` returns the correct class because you pass in the `Class<T>` and its signature is also equivalent to `public <T> T readValue(..., Class<T> clazz)`, so you can just do:

```
T obj = getResponseJsonMapper.readValue(getResponseJson, responseType);        
return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use T as return parameter and cast(assuming a cast is possible - otherwise you get a runtime exception).

```
public static <T> T getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException{
    Response getResponse = callWithHttpGet(url);
    String getResponseJson = getResponse.getBody();
    ObjectMapper getResponseJsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T obj = (T)getResponseJsonMapper.readValue(getResponseJson, responseType);        
    return obj;
}
```

And well in the particular case you might even skip the cast(if the ObjectMapper already returns the correct type - eg Jackson).